# Functional inequality $f(x)\cdot \cos( x-y)\le f(y)$.

Tags: functional-inequalities

I am doing special manual of functional equations. While i was searching problems for my book, i have found this: Find all continuous functions $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) \cdot \cos(x-y)\le f(y)$.

The answer is easy, but i don't know how to prove it. $f(x)=c, c\ge 0$

It's not difficult to prove, that $f(x+2\pi)=f(x)$, but i don't know the next move of solution.
The only way i see how to solve this is to prove that $f'(x)\ge 0$

$\displaystyle f'(x)=\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \dfrac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x} \ge \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \dfrac{f(x)(\cos \Delta x - 1)}{\Delta x}=0$. But in the task not given, that f is differentiable.

Comment: It is periodic so bounded (assuming continuous), so, if not constant it would have a maximum. But if $x_0$ is a local maximum then there are larger values around $x_0$ based on the inequality,

Comment: Why do larger values around $x_0$ exist?

Comment: because $f(y) >= 0$ (easy to prove) and the inequality. That is take $x_0$ and $y$ close to $x_0$ since $\cos t < 1$ for $t != 0$ you get the claim.

Comment: I don't understand. We can have $f(x_0)\cdot\cos (x_0-y) \le f(y)$. But $\cos (x_0-y)$ can equal, for example  $\frac{1}{2}$. And we have $f(x_0) \le 2 f(y)$. It doesn't do anything. if we switch $x_0$ and $y$ it doesn't do anything too. 

Sorry for my poor english. I am from another country

Comment: I am talking about local max. Have you taken a course in Analysis 1?

Comment: I am studying at school. Yes, local maximum $f'(x)=0$. But there is nothing in task about derivative

Comment: Related: [AoPS thread](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1731252p11224501), found using [Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f(x)%20%5Ccdot%20%5Ccos(x-y)%5Cle%20f(y)%24&p=1).

Comment: Oh, that was so easy... Thanks a lot!!

Comment: It isn't a functional *equ*ation (with an *equa*l sign) as you write it in your title but a functional *inequa*lity.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me!